# Using build system to run tests or interact with clusters

Tags: bazel

What is the purpose of projects like these below that use Bazel for things other than building software?

- https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_webtesting
- https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s

Are they just conveniently providing environment for `run` command (as opposed to building portable executables) or am I missing something?

The best I can tell is that Bazel could be used to run only subset of E2E tests based on knowledge what changed.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I have only cursory knowledge about k8s and docker.

Bazel isn't just used for building and testing, it can also deploy, as you've discovered with the rules in those projects.

> The best I can tell is that Bazel could be used to run only subset of E2E tests based on knowledge what changed.

Correct, but also extend tests to deployments. If you've only changed a single string in your Go binary that's injected into an image, Bazel is able to use rules_k8s, rules_docker, and rules_go to:

1. incrementally and reproducibly rebuild the minimum set files to
   build the new Go executable
2. create a new image layer containing the Go executable (without using Docker)
3. push the image to the registry
4. redeploy changed pod(s) into cluster

The notable thing is that if you *didn't change* the source file, Bazel will always create an image with the same digest due to its reproducibility. That means that you can now trust the deployment workflow to *not* redeploy/restart a pod even if you do a `bazel run` twice or more.

For more, check out this BazelCon 2017 talk: [Using Bazel for Fast, Correct Docker Deployments w/ Databricks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS1aiQqgUTA)

Fun fact: you can also use `bazel run` to start a REPL for your build target, from 0.15.0 onwards. [Haskell](http://haskell.build/haskell/haskell.html) and [Scala](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala#scala_repl) rules use this.